# About AVL tree and their height - is there a mistake in our readings script?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, avl-tree

I learn for exam and I use our script too for learn. I agree with all step but I don't understand the red circle ) I make it read for you). Because there is the tree root balance `-1`. How can this be correct?

The balance of the left subtree of the root `10` is `-4`, its right subtree has balance `+2`, so in total we have `-4+2 = -2 = unbalanced after insertion of 8`. But how our professor has `-1` as result?

I understand something wrong here?

[image]

Comment: @cricket_007 Oh yes I used wrong word, but balance must be -2 or not? Maybe you can explain how is it -1?

Comment: After 9 is inserted, it's also -1, so why aren't you confused there?

Comment: Ok I think I calculate balance value wrong. How you do it correctly? Let say we want left balance value of 10. We always go to left till we are at a leaf, right? In this case we have -3 (if we also count the root), correct?

Comment: I don't understand what you're counting. The only valid values are -1, 0, and 1 for a balance. It's just the way to the heavier side of the tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially have the exact same weight difference in step 2 and 4. Yes, the tree is imbalanced, and that's being marked by `*p` and `φp` , which I assume you were taught are the rotation points

The negative one is just the notation of the weight "lean"

Comment: That mean the last tree is not balance, so it's no AVL tree and we would have to rotate which isn't shown in example?

Comment: @Hamudii Yes its not balanced.

Comment: @Hamudii It is still an AVL tree. The final state of the tree isn't shown